# Add Class to parent that has child with some CSS

Tags: jquery

I want to check and see if some elements have children with specific CSS attributes. I then want to add a class to only those parents that do have a child with that CSS attribute.

Here is the script I am working on:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if ($('.child').css('display') === 'block') {
            $(this).parent().addClass( "newClass" );
    };
});
```

The issue seems to be that $(this) does not target any child elements that make the above function true. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.child:visible').parent().addClass('newClass');
```

Assuming that you are trying to identify visible children. If it's actually only children with block display then there are alternatives too.

Comment: Doh! That makes a ton of sense. I think i misread the jQuery documentation when I read about :visible.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.child:visible').parent().addClass('newClass');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Should use a jQuery loop because actually $(this) is not a reference to the element you want

```
$('.child').each(function() { 
    if ($(this).css('display') === 'block') {
            $(this).parent().addClass( "newClass" );
    };
});
```

try something like that.